# materialDesign:DialogHost dialog closes when trying to open file from FileOpenDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, double-click, material-design-in-xaml

I have a control within a `<materialDesign:DialogHost CloseOnClickAway="True" />` that opens a system `FileOpenDialog`. If I double click in the `FileOpenDialog` to open a file, the background dialog in the host closes. I've narrowed it down that the file dialog closes on the second <kbd>mouse-down</kbd> and the application responds to the subsequent <kbd>mouse-up</kbd> event.

Any suggestions on how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came up with a solution albeit it feels a little hackish. The `<materialDesign:DialogHost />` has a property `DialogClosing` that allows you to specify a callback as the closing event is fired. In the code-behind, I created an event handler `public void MainViewModel_CheckIfDialogShouldClose(object sender, DialogClosingEventArgs e)` that calls a subclassed `FileOpenDialog`'s `WasOpenRecently` function. This function returns `true`/`false` if the dialog was closed within the last 250 milliseconds. If we get `true` back, we `e.Cancel();` to cancel the `DialogHost`'s closing event.